# JSoup Elements removes duplicates automatically

Tags: android, jsoup, element

This is a weird problem which I don't understand why it would occur. But, doing the following:

```
Elements Fullcoursespaces = fullCourses.select("span[class=note-red]"); //Get the course times
```

Removes duplicates. So it returns two unique elements, but since the rest of the elements are duplicates of these unique elements, they are removed. When instead, it should fill up the elements list with the duplicates regardless. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Edit: As a side note, doing document.querySelectorAll("span[class=note-red]"); on the webpage gives me all the elements regardless if they are duplicates or not.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What is a "duplicate" in your eyes? Can you post the relevant parts of the html document you try to parse?

Comment: Which version of Jsoup are you using? Moreover provide a sample in order to test this behavior.

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. This is another question in SO describing the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164170/jsoup-1-8-3-missing-element . If you check the changelog of the project, there were some problems https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/CHANGES . Maybe you should report your finding

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, I'm trying to parse a website and I can't get the data from the table correctly as the jsoap just removes the duplicates and the headers don't match contents of the table then, This is so bad! I can't believe they left a bug like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Jsoup.select.Elements with duplicate data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987678/how-to-create-a-jsoup-select-elements-with-duplicate-data)