# Jsoup 1.8.3 missing element

Tags: android, jsoup

I have been using Jsoup 1.7.2 for about a year and thought of updating to version 1.8.3.
I have stumbled across an issue, please check it out:
Here is the document:

```
<dl class="a"> 
 <dt>
  Total transfers
 </dt> 
 <dd>
  2
 </dd> 
 <dt>
  Gameweek transfers
 </dt> 
 <dd>
  2
 </dd> 
</dl>
<dl class="b"> 
 <dt>
  Team value
 </dt> 
 <dd>
  £99.2m
 </dd>
 <dt>
  In the bank
 </dt> 
 <dd>
  £0.3m
 </dd>
</dl>
```

Now when I try to select "dd" like `doc.select("dd")`, it returns an element with size 3 :

```
<dd>
 2
</dd>
<dd>
 £99.2m
</dd>
<dd>
 £0.3m
</dd>
```

Ideally in the older version it used to return all the 4 elements.
It could be because the first two "dd" are duplicates.
Is this a bug or a feature and can you tell me how to get all the 4 elements?

Comment: for me this is not reproducible. I find 4 dd elements using Jsoup 1.8.3

Comment: Me neither, please recheck and post your code.

Comment: Using the same code, just changing the library back to 1.7.2 works. Infact I tried 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.1 and these work absolutely fine. Version 1.8.2 and 1.8.3 dont seem to work.

Comment: I've tried it too and no problem was found. How did you include the jsoup library to your project? Did you use maven or did you download the jar? Try changing the value of one of the duplicates and see if the problem persists. I think I've seen another question here in SO about duplicates not appearing correctly and it might be that a wrong version of jsoup is uploaded. Try downloading the jsoup library from the maven repo

Comment: I used the jar file as I am not familiar with maven. If I change the value of the duplicate, it is working fine. Also I have tested this on all major versions of android from 2.3.3

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. This is the other question in SO describing the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040601/jsoup-elements-removes-duplicates-automatically . If you check the changelog of the project, there were some problems https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/CHANGES . Maybe you should  report your finding

Comment: Starting from version 1.8.2 there were some performance tweaking that introduced some problems. These problems were fixed and are not reproducible in desktop applications (the code runs fine in my J2SE program), but for some reason, when in Android JRE there is a problem. You can investigate further. I will do too, but since I'm not an android developer it will take me some time

Comment: Thank you so much for confirming. I am awaiting a response from the dev of jsoup.

Comment: When you do, don't forget to post an answer here and accept it. This way others can benefit too. Have fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this issue has been solved and will be fixed in the next version of jsoup

Ref : https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/614