# can't get duplicated tags using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm parsing `.html` file using `Jsoup`. 
And I got a `<tr>` tag. 
This `<tr>` tag has following contents :

```
<tr height="40" align="center"> 
    <td class="small" style="padding-top: 5px;" bgcolor="#f1f1f1"><strong>Data1</strong><span class="small1"><br>time1</span></td> 
    <td align="center" class="small">&nbsp;</td> 
    <td align="center" class="small">&nbsp;</td> 
    <td align="center" class="small" bgcolor="#eeeeee" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td> 
    <td align="center" class="small">&nbsp;</td> 
    <td align="center" class="small">&nbsp;</td> 
    <td align="center" class="small" bgcolor="#eeeeee" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td> 
    <td align="center" class="small">&nbsp;</td> 
    <td class="small" style="padding-top: 5px;" bgcolor="#eeeeee" rowspan="2"><strong>Data2</strong><span class="small1"><br>time2</span></td> 
</tr>
```

And I need each `<td>` tags above. 
So, I tried the code using `Elements.selector()` like this :

```java
String str;
int size;
// ...
Elements elems;    // it has <tr> tag above.
// ...
str = elems.select("td").toString();
size = elems.select("td").size();
```

So I think now `size` should be `9` and `str` should has below value :

```
<td class="small" style="padding-top: 5px;" bgcolor="#f1f1f1"><strong>Data1</strong><span class="small1"><br>time1</span></td> 
<td align="center" class="small">&nbsp;</td> 
<td align="center" class="small">&nbsp;</td> 
<td align="center" class="small" bgcolor="#eeeeee" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td> 
<td align="center" class="small">&nbsp;</td> 
<td align="center" class="small">&nbsp;</td> 
<td align="center" class="small" bgcolor="#eeeeee" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td> 
<td align="center" class="small">&nbsp;</td> 
<td class="small" style="padding-top: 5px;" bgcolor="#eeeeee" rowspan="2"><strong>Data2</strong><span class="small1"><br>time2</span></td>
```

But, when I compiled this code, 
`size` was `4` and `str` was like below :

```
<td class="small" style="padding-top: 5px;" bgcolor="#f1f1f1"><strong>Data1</strong><span class="small1"><br>time1</span></td>
<td align="center" class="small">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center" class="small" bgcolor="#eeeeee" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="small" style="padding-top: 5px;" bgcolor="#eeeeee" rowspan="2"><strong>Data2</strong><span class="small1"><br>time2</span></td>
```

I think duplicated `<td>` tags are removed... 
I don't get it. I need all of `<td>` tags. 
Did I something wrong?

Comment: this seems to be a common problem, see this thread [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040601/jsoup-elements-removes-duplicates-automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040601/jsoup-elements-removes-duplicates-automatically)

Comment: @ralfhtp Thank you for your comment. So I should downgrade the `Jsoup` to `1.7` version, or wait for a new version... Thanks

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34987678/363573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like problem/bug appears when you call `select("td")` on `Elements` (plural) holding `tr`, but it disappears when you can on `Element` (singular) which represents single `tr`.

So if you have only one `tr` you can simply pick `first()` `Element` and `select("td")` on it.

```
str = elems.first().select("td").toString();
size = elems.first().select("td").size();
```

In case of more `tr` iterate over all of them like

```
for (Element tr : elems){
   //^^^^^^^^^^ - element holding single tr
    Elements tds = tr.select("td");
    System.out.println(tds);
    System.out.println("---------");
    System.out.println(tds.size());  
}
```

Problem also disappears when we call `select("tr td")` instead of `select("tr").select("td")` (in both cases we are trying to select all `td` from all `tr`).

Answer (score 0):

On https://blog.tallan.com/2012/07/26/parsing-html-using-jsoup-library/ is a way to get all rows of a table:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_blogs").get();
```

[...]

```
Elements trs = doc.select("table.wikitable tr");
```

*table means we want to ‘select a table’, . means ‘with CSS class named’, wikitable actually identifies the CSS class we’re looking for,* **and ‘tr‘ means ‘and then get all the table rows that follow.’**

here is an overview over most selectors:
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax