# How to create a Jsoup.select.Elements with duplicate data?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have a web-page:

```html
<table id="timetable" class="table gradient-table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td  class="time">
      <div>10:30 12:05</div>
      </td>
      <td  class="time">
      <div>12:30 14:05</div>
      </td>
      <td  class="time">
      <div>12:30 14:05</div>
      </td>
      <td  class="time">
      <div>14:30 16:05</div>
      </td>
      <td  class="time">
      <div>16:30 18:05</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am doing:

```
doc.select("table[id=timetable]").select("tbody").select("td[class=time]");
```

I should get:

```
10:30 12:05
12:30 14:05
12:30 14:05
14:30 16:05
16:30 18:05
but I got:
10:30 12:05
12:30 14:05
14:30 16:05
16:30 18:05
```

am I doing right?

Comment: it was bug in jsoup  what version you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have hit a known issue from Jsoup (see [luksch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34989072/363573) for details). However, here is a workaround working on `Jsoup 1.8.3`.

```
table#timetable > tbody > tr > td.time
```

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String html = "<table id=\"timetable\" class=\"table gradient-table\">\n<tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <td  class=\"time\">\n      <div>10:30 12:05</div>\n      </td>\n      <td  class=\"time\">\n      <div>12:30 14:05</div>\n      </td>\n      <td  class=\"time\">\n      <div>12:30 14:05</div>\n      </td>\n      <td  class=\"time\">\n      <div>14:30 16:05</div>\n      </td>\n      <td  class=\"time\">\n      <div>16:30 18:05</div>\n      </td>\n    </tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

for (Element elt : doc.select("table#timetable > tbody > tr > td.time")) {
    System.out.println(elt.text());
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
10:30 12:05
12:30 14:05
12:30 14:05
14:30 16:05
16:30 18:05
```

**Tested on Jsoup 1.8.3**

Comment: Everything's fine! (on Jsoup 1.8.3) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You came across a known bug in JSoup 1.8.2 & JSoup 1.8.3. See issue [#614](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/614) and [#664](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/664)

To avoid this you should downgrade to Jsoup version 1.8.1 if possible or make sure to not use the select method of the Elements (plural!) class. CSS selectors on single elements or the whole dolument seem to be not affected, so you can also go with the solution of @Stephan.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems Jsoup is using `LinkedHashSet` internally which may the source of this bug...

Comment: The bug seems already fixed in the development branch but for some reason there is no bugfix release made available yet, which is a real shame. See https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/CHANGES

Comment: jhy may be overwhelmed :\